# Elliptic Curve Family "KSS16" arithmetic implementation in C (on embedded devices)

Tags: c, cryptography, arm

could someone help me find a running implementation of those families? I did some search through google by the terms

```
* KSS16 implementation in C
* KSS16 benchmark on embedded( devices)
* KSS16 benchmark
* KSS16 embed
* KSS16 (optimal) ate-pairing
```

and close to that. Is there any DB that stores actual implementations?

I would like to run an optimale ate-pairing with kss16 at actual 128 and 192-bits of security, since the older parametersets are raised, BN is not the fastest at 128-bits, anymore.

I found a lib [1], that includes some arithmetics. Does someone knows a little "crawler", to find the file, that contains the arithmetics?

I need a lib at 32-bits.

Thank you for helping me.

[1] https://github.com/relic-toolkit/relic

Comment: still looking for.